# How to store previous page even if I refresh the page in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I wanted to store previous page although users refresh the page. I used

```
  beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    next(vm => {
      vm.prevRoute = from
    })
  },
```

to store `this.prevRoute.path` into Data. However, I realized once I refresh the current page, my path is gone. I wonder if there is anyway I can restore the previous page.

Comment: Maybe you could store the data in the browser's localStorage : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Thank you for the advice @Thoomas Would you provide exact example? I tried with using setItem but it changes its' path every time I refresh the page..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**users refresh the page**, for this purpose you can either use

- Local Storage
- Cookies

To give an example, you can do something like this

```
// To save the path
localStorage.setItem("prevRoutePath", thePathYouWant);

// To get the saved path
const prevPath = localStorage.getItem("prevRoutePath") ?? "fallback"; // You can get this whenever you want.
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your idea @rago! I tried this and I got other issues. Every time I refresh the page, beforeRouteEnter runs too and the preRoute is updated to new prevous page therefore, I can't keep the previous page that was before refresh. Do you have any other idea that I can keep previous page beside cookies, or localStorage?

Comment: @Cindy to keep the previous check, at the beginning of **beforeRouteEnter**, check if there is a saved path.

Comment: Would you explain little more? do you mean, I should add functionality to check if there is saved path before I set "setItem"?

Comment: Yes, totally @Cindy